# parsing bad JSON

Tags: json, ruby

The following snippet creates a failure point when validating the file with jsonlint.com
`"description": "\#$CS-4 PZ",`
derived from the  pattern `\#$`.

The back slash is the offending character as removing it allows to continue processing the file, until a subsequent back slash is encountered.
This file is transmitted to the local rails API, probably by a windows issuer.

How can it be pre-processed in ruby to remove the offending back slash?

Comment: It's not that the backslash \ must be removed, but escaped itself by another backslash. The following JSON:

`{ "description": "\\#$CS-4 PZ" }`

is valid. You need to escape \ characters.

Comment: It should really be considered if your app really should be accepting broken JSON in the first place. While it might be convient for this user you're inviting all kinds of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action is, as max says in comments, not to accept bad JSON. But if you can't help it...

You can see at json.org what the valid escape sequences are, and strip backslashes that don't fit:

```
bad_json = "\\# is bad but \\u0020, \\\\ and \\n are good"

json = bad_json.gsub(/(\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}))|\\/, '\1')
puts json
# => # is bad but \u0020, \\ and \n are good
```

If you want to preserve the odd backslashes:

```
json = bad_json.gsub(/(\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[a-fA-F0-9]{4}))|(\\)/, '\1\2\2')
puts json
# => \\# is bad but \u0020, \\ and \n are good
```